# How to parse Socket IO incoming data in Swift

Tags: swift, socket.io

I'm building a board game app that connects through sockets and I am having problems parsing socket data.

I am new to Swift btw, so any help would be appreciated.

What I am trying to accomplish is to update an Observable object with incoming socket data

I am able to emit data, but I am having a hard time with the incoming.

Can some one please give me a hand on this?

Here is my code:

I have a board map struct:

```
struct BoardMap: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var p1: [Int]
    var p2: [Int]
    var n1: Int
    var n2: Int
    var playersDraft: [Int]
    var allPieces: [PieceInfo]
}
```

And an ObservableObject class with the socket connection and the @Published object boardMap that is used on the game view.

```
class BoardViewModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published var boardMap: BoardMap = initialBoardMap
       @Published var status: String = "queue"
       @Published var isConnected: Bool = false
        
       let socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:7000")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
       @Published var socket: SocketIO.SocketIOClient
                
       init(userId: [String]) {
          socket = socketManager.defaultSocket
          socket.connect()
          socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { data, ack in
          self.isConnected = true
          self.socket.emit("join_room", ["id" : "1234"])
          self.socket.emit("loadGame", ["id": "1234", "userId": "12345"])
          self.socket.emit("startMatch", ["id": "1234", "userId": "12345"])
       }
                    
       socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { data, ack in
         self.isConnected = false
         print("Socket has disconnected")
        }
        
}
```

and the func I receive data:

```
        self.socket.on("boardMap") { [unowned self] data, ack in
            print(type(of:data))
            print(type(of:data[0]))
            self.boardMap.allPieces = (data[0] as AnyObject)["allPieces"]! as! [PieceInfo]
         
        }
    }
```

For type of data I get Array

For type of data[0]  I get __NSDictionaryM

Ideally what I want to do is boardmap.allPieces = data.allPieces
Which becomes:
`self.boardMap.allPieces = (data[0] as AnyObject)["allPieces"]! as! [PieceInfo]` but it throws an error.

I'm getting this:

**Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x7f99d604bf38) to 'Lgame_ios.PieceInfo' (0x1086072c8).**

After I realize data[0] is actually a dictionary I've tried to iterate over it.

```
for item in data { // loop through data items
            let obj = item as! NSDictionary
            for (key, value) in obj {
                self.updateBoard(key: key, value: value)
            }
        }


func updateBoard(key: Any, value: Any) -> Void {
    if(key as! String as AnyObject === "allPieces" as AnyObject) {
        print(value)
        boardmap.allPieces = value
    }

}
```

but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

change NSDictionary to Dictionary<String,Any>

Comment: can you share console log screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in data { // loop through data items
    let obj = item as! [String: AnyObject]
    if let val = obj["allPieces"] {
       self.updateBoard(key: "allPieces", value: val)
    }
}

func updateBoard(key: String, value: Any) {
    boardMap.allPieces = value
}
```